# UV unwrap causing texture to warp

Tags: texturing, uv

So here is the front face of the house i'm modelling. it's completely flat of course. Once i tried to UV unwrap it all the edges are going off in strange angles making the texture applied looking warped. The left window is particularly severe in this case

[image]

(the texture on  the interior doesn't matter since it cant be seen once rendered)

I watched a blender guru video and he mentioned that i should keep all faces with 4 edges, creating a square so that's what i've tried to do throughout this project. Can provide any additional pictures or info if needed.

Any help much appreciated thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your model done, then do the unwrap. It looks like you are trying to do the unwrap as you go, and the model is not square and level in relation to the vertex positions. If you select all the faces there in the front of the object and in the matching view select 'project from view' then the texture should not warp - but you will need to do this for each side of the model, and you will have to adjust for scale matched to the texture.